# Extract and display values from JSON array in Select Statement in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-16

I am developing some code to extract values directly from a text field containing JSON in a JSON array

I want to be able to display the values along with an ID (using Row_Number) but struggling.

Also i want to run this in a simple test harness script without having to create a function with a Return Table statement.

Is this possible ?

OK here is my code:

```
DO $TESTS$
    DECLARE json text;


BEGIN
    json := '{ "Devices" : [ "894339" , "907578" , "926371", "939029", "940860", "958623", "960232"] }';


 SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY SerialNumber::text) as ID,
        json::json ->> 'Devices' as SerialNumber
 FROM (SELECT JSON::json AS JSON2) AS jsonData; ) AS Subquery;

END;
$TESTS$
```

And here is the error I get

```
[2023-11-23 16:18:05] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
[2023-11-23 16:18:05] Position: 320
```

My desired output is :

```
ID      SerialNumber
1       894338
2       907578 
3       926371
4       939029
5       940860
6       958623
7       960232
```

Comment: What does "*from a text field*" mean? Does this value actually come from a table? Or are you writing a function that receives an argument?

Comment: a) don't use a `text` field, use `jsonb` (or `json`) b) you're looking for [the `jsonb_array_elements_text` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

Comment: @Bergi i am writing a functon which will take in JSON in the form of a text field . This being passed from a C# application. 

Hence why i was trying to cast the value for Json to JSON

Comment: Then declare the function as taking `jsonb` (or `json`) right away. You can still call it using a normal parameterised query (eg `SELECT my_function($1)`) from C#, passing a JSON string.

Comment: OK I figured this out. 
I had to do the following

   create table tmp
        (
            c JSONB
        );

Then         insert into tmp
        values ('{ "Devices" : [ "894339" , "907578" , "926371", "939029", "940860", "958623", "960232"] }');

then I can run the following code 

        SELECT SerialNumber from tmp
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL             json_array_elements_text(c:: json -> 'Devices') as SerialNumber;

Comment: Yes, that's what you would use if you need to run this on multiple values (that you can all store in the temp table). But you don't strictly *need* the temp table, in particular for just a single value it would be easier to pass the literal value (that you currently pass to the `INSERT` query) directly to the `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a temporary table, you can simply select from the output of [`json_array_elements_text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY value) as ID, value AS SerialNumber
FROM json_array_elements_text(json -> 'Devices');
```

Output:

```
id  serialnumber
1   894339
2   907578
3   926371
4   939029
5   940860
6   958623
7   960232
```

Note as @Bergi points out, you can declare the `json` value as type json from the beginning. If you don't, you'll need to cast it to type json in the call to `json_array_elements_text` i.e. `json_array_elements_text(json::json -> 'Devices')`.

Comment: thanks so much for your help on this. 
I elected to use the suggestion from Nick as follows:
      SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY value) as ID, value AS SerialNumber
      FROM json_array_elements_text(json::json -> 'Devices');